# PHP Defined Constant and mktime() Do Not Agree

Tags: php, constants, mktime

I'm trying to establish a maximum timestamp setting for a given hosting environment and set a constant with that value. I wrote the following:

```
define('SC_TIME_END_OF_64', mktime(23, 59, 59, 12, 31, 9999));
```

If I then display the two values on a system known to have 64-bit integers and 64-bit time:

```
echo SC_TIME_END_OF_64 . ' ' . mktime(23, 59, 59, 12, 31, 9999);
```

I get:

```
253402300799 253402318799
```

My constant is 18000 seconds too small.

Then I tried:

```
if (mktime(23, 59, 59, 12, 31, 9999) == 253402318799) {
```

That conditional resolves to false. If I substitute 253402300799, it will resolve to true.

Finally, I tried:

```
$time_64 = mktime(23, 59, 59, 12, 31, 9999);
echo $time_64;
```

And I get the expected answer:

```
253402318799
```

I'm stumped. What don't I understand about constants?

Comment: What are the timezone settings for your server? and are you changing these in your code? Try the same exercise with `gmmktime()` - `when called with no arguments, gmmktime() uses the current GMT time, and mktime() uses the current local time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is a timezone issue. If you do the two statements right next to each other it works:

```
define('SC_TIME_END_OF_64', mktime(23, 59, 59, 12, 31, 9999));
echo SC_TIME_END_OF_64 . ' ' . mktime(23, 59, 59, 12, 31, 9999);
//253402329599 253402329599
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73e441ef17890152380b6c875157596e0287a1b6

But if you change the timezone at some point in between you get different results:

```
define('SC_TIME_END_OF_64', mktime(23, 59, 59, 12, 31, 9999));
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
echo SC_TIME_END_OF_64 . ' ' . mktime(23, 59, 59, 12, 31, 9999);
//253402329599 253402297199
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/795bede12ac82b69b360bf8cae9bcd9eebc2ebf4

Either standardize on a timezone (ideally UTC), or use `gmmktime()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. The time zone is being set later in the code and because it wasn't near the place where I made the constant, I missed it. 18000 seconds is 5 hours, so I should have realized it.